# vue-table-2 with Vuex - not able to change the count property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm using the vue-table-2 component : https://github.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2 and I'm struggling to make it work as I want.

I have an API (using API Platform) which is already making all the pagination works. So when I fetch for the first time my list of companies it gives the first ten results + the total rows. I store all of this in my vuex store and I am able to display the list in my table (with useVuex false or true so I don't really understand how this parameter works). The issue is I cannot paginate because I only got ten results and can't get the total rows count to change so I do not get the pagination element at the bottom and can't bind something to it to fetch the other pages later.

Since I'm pretty new to VueJs I can't figure out how this should work with my API. Here is my code so far:

My DataTable element :

```
<v-client-table name="company" :columns="columns" :data="companies" :options="options" :theme="theme" id="dataTable">
          <b-button slot="actions" slot-scope="props" variant="secondary" size="sm" class="btn-pill">Edit</b-button>
</v-client-table>
```

And my script :

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import { ClientTable, Event } from 'vue-tables-2'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

Vue.use(ClientTable)

export default {
  name: 'DataTable',
  components: {
    ClientTable,
    Event,
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      columns: ['name', 'actions'],
      options: {
        headings: {
          name: 'Name',
          actions: 'Actions',
        },
        sortable: ['name'],
        filterable: ['name'],
        sortIcon: {
          base: 'fa',
          up: 'fa-sort-asc',
          down: 'fa-sort-desc',
          is: 'fa-sort',
        },
        pagination: {
          chunk: 5,
          edge: false,
          nav: 'scroll',
        },
      },
      useVuex: true,
      theme: 'bootstrap4',
      template: 'default',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      companies: 'companyModule/companies',
      totalCompanies: 'companyModule/totalCompanies',
    }),
  },
}
</script>
```

This is in my component loading the data where I specify how many items per page I want my api to send me and the page I want:

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('companyModule/FETCH_COMPANIES', {
      page: 1,
      nbItemPerPage: 10,
    })
  },
```

My store looks like this:

```
import ApiService from '@/services/APIService'

export const companyModule = {
  strict: true,
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    companies: [],
    totalCompanies: 0,
  },
  getters: {
    companies: state => state.companies,
    totalCompanies: state => state.totalCompanies,
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_COMPANIES(state, data) {
      state.companies = data.companies
      state.totalCompanies = data.totalCompanies
    },
  },
  actions: {
    FETCH_COMPANIES(context, payload) {
      payload.entity = 'companies'
      return ApiService.get(payload).then(data => {
        context.commit('SET_COMPANIES', data)
      })
    },
  },
}
```

When I received my data, I stored everything in my companies state and for now I'm storing everything I'm getting from my API and this looks like this :

```
{
      "@id": "/api/admin/companies/1",
      "@type": "Company",
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Test Company",
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: how did getting that data from api, please show the code that does that

Comment: At the creation my list view I have :

Comment: At the creation my list view I have :

  created() {
      this.$store.dispatch('companyModule/FETCH_COMPANIES', {
        page: 1,
        nbItemPerPage: 10,
      })
    },

This action fetch API giving me 10 results per page and giving me the the 10 results on page 1. Then I store all my result in my store this is the format of one item stored : 

  {
        "@id": "/api/admin/companies/1",
        "@type": "Company",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test Company"
  }

Hope this helps !

Comment: could you edit the question by adding these details to be more clear

Comment: I Just made the edit, sorry I'm not use yet to make posts on Stack Overflow !

Comment: did you try to customize your apiservice?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you ask but my APIService is working, I'm not sure the problem is here what do you think the problem could be ? I need to set the count (or find the clean way to do the pagination) on my vue-table-2 client-table with the data I get from my API.

Comment: i mean that  did you try a way to customize that api to provide all data without pagination

Comment: If I provide all data directly I get the pagination as I want but I would like to fetch only a certain amount of items because this is more scalable when the database will have a lot of data. This is why I would like the table to know that I will have let's say 100 results (this will display the pagination element at the bottom) and on changePage event fetch the data for the specific page. (I hope I'm clear sorry If I'm not :s )

Answer (score 0):

```
watch: {
    'companies': {
    handler (newValue, oldValue) {
        this.totalRows=this.companies.length;
    },
    deep: true
    }
},
```

Vue “watch” is a powerful reactive option attribute to the vue framework that helps front-end developers listen to changes made on a value and then react to it.
So, once the totalRows is set, you can assign it to the table attributes and the table will change accordingly.
For my case, I used it for bootstrap table as follows:

```
    <b-pagination
        :total-rows="totalRows"
        :per-page="perPage"
></b-pagination>
```